# Вывод input по мере заполнения

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.
У меня есть самая простая форма:

```
<form>
  <input type=“Text”>
  <input type=“Text”>
  <input type=“Text”>
</form>
```

По умолчанию показывается только первое поле. Как после его заполнения вывести второе и так далее?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простейший вариант без JS:

```css
input:valid + input { display: initial; }
input:invalid ~ input { display: none; }
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" required placeholder="Введите имя" pattern="[a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ]+">
  <input type="number" required placeholder="Введите возраст">
  <input type="e-mail" required placeholder="Введите E-mail" pattern="[a-zA-Z-]+@[a-zA-Z-]+\.[a-zA-Z-]{2,6}">
  <input type="button" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Как дополнительный бонус - можно сразу указать предварительные условия, для появления следующего поля, через атрибут *pattern*. Атрибут *placeholder* добавлен для наглядности.

Answer (score 2):

Вот такой примитивный пример. Добавления нового input по наполнению

```js
[...document.getElementsByTagName("input")].forEach(item => item.addEventListener("keyup", addNewInput));
 
 
function addNewInput(event) {
  if (event.target.value.length == 10) { 
    this.removeEventListener("keyup", addNewInput);
    let input = document.createElement("input");
    form.appendChild(input);
    input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    input.setAttribute('maxlength', '10');
    input.addEventListener("keyup", addNewInput);
    input.focus();
  }
  
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="Text" maxlength="10">
</form>
```